# Add Custom No Data To Display for ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

How can i add a custom no data to display for ngx-datatable.
I don't want the no data to display that comes with ngx-datatable.

What i tried is below

```
<div *ngIf="showTable">
   <ngx-datatable [rows]="rows">
    <div *ngIf="searchDataNotFound" >
          <img src="nodata.png"/>
            <span> No Contacts to display</span>
      </div> 
  <div class="clear-search-text"(click)="clearSearch(searchComponentHook)>Clear Search</div>
     <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of columns" 
     [name]="column.name">
      .....
       <ngx-datatable-column>
     
 <ngx-datatable>
 .........
```

Like this I am keeping a div to show the no data found. the searchDataNotFound flag will be true when there is no data and is false when there is data.
But it is not showing at all. Its Showing only the no data to display from ngx-datatable.

Thanks

Comment: I got the solution. I had to place the div outside of ng-datatable tag

Answer (score 2):

Better way you can directly  add custom text for empty array to ngx datatable with property.
Like this.

```
[messages]="{emptyMessage: 'No Contacts to display'}"
```

you can see the exmple:

```
<ngx-datatable
            #tabData
            class="bootstrap mt-3"
            [columnMode]="'force'"
            headerHeight="50"
            footerHeight="50"
            rowHeight="60"
            [limit]="10"
            [scrollbarH]="true"
            [count]="totalCount"
            [offset]="pageNumber"
            [externalPaging]="true"
            (page)="setPage($event)"[rows]="rows" [messages]="{emptyMessage: 'No Contacts to display'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra closing ">" on the div before your *ngIf.

Comment: actually i dont have any compilation issue. that was a printing mistake.

Comment: Ah okay. Often times when using ng conditionals, I like to use an else statement pointing to ng-template. This way you can see when it is not passing and may be able to pinpoint the error. 
`<div *ngIf="searchDataNotFound; else foo">...</div>`